# Launching a powershell script with ExecutionPolicy ByPass but not working

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to run a ps script in a computer that has execution policy is restricted.

I cannot change this policy, so I am trying to run the script in this way:

```
.\Script.ps1 -ExecutionPolicy ByPass
```

But I am still getting the error:

> cannot be loaded because the execution of scripts is disabled on this system

The system is a Windows Server 2008 R2 with PowerShell 2.0

**EDIT:**

```
Get-ExecutionPolicy -List
          Scope                                             ExecutionPolicy
          -----                                             ---------------
  MachinePolicy                                                   Undefined
     UserPolicy                                                   Undefined
        Process                                                   Undefined
    CurrentUser                                                   Undefined
   LocalMachine                                                   Undefined
```

Comment: Have you tried to run as administrator ?

Comment: Yes, and I get the same

Comment: What does Get-Executionpolicy come back as? Can you try using Set-ExecutionPolicy rather than using the -ExecutionPolicy parameter?

Comment: Get-Executionpolicy returns "Restricted" and if I try using Set-ExecutionPolicy the script is run, but this doesn't resolve my problem. I need to run this script in any machine without using Set-ExecutionPolicy sentence.

Comment: i THINK the bypass is only valid with powershell.exe ... and you are not passing that parameter to the exe - you are passing it to the _script_.

Comment: `-ExecutionPolicy` is a parameter of `powershell.exe`. You seem to be running the script from a PowerShell console, so `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` would just be passed as a parameter to your script. Run it like this: `powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File .\Script.ps1`.

Comment: That could be right, but if I launch C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe .\Script.ps1 -ExecutionPolicy ByPass I get the same (through an Administrator cmd)

Comment: Please show the output of `Get-ExecutionPolicy -List`.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers, I've edited the post for you.

Comment: Didn't you say `Get-ExecutionPolicy` returned "Restricted"? Also, why are you running a 32-bit PowerShell?

Comment: Get-ExecutionPolicy returns "Restricted" and I use a 32-bit PS because I use a Oracle Provider that only works under 32 bits.

Comment: Something is odd about your PowerShell. Please run `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File .\Script.ps1` from a Command Prompt.

Comment: I think @AnsgarWiechers hit the nail on the head... I'm almost sure the problem was the order of the parameters. I did not write the file name at the end... In this order I don't need -NoProfile parameter. C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File .\Script.ps1 Thanks all and sorry for the inconvenience... :S

Comment: No, the order of the parameters shouldn't have that effect. If the command works with the parameter `-NoProfile` but doesn't work without it, you may want to check your [profiles](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/05/21/understanding-the-six-powershell-profiles.aspx) for things that might cause this behavior.

Comment: It works with and without `-NoProfile`. I have checked that the order was the culprit...